# How to properly generate a random gradient background?

Tags: ios, random, uiview

I've been trying to create a function that generates a random gradient background every time a new view controller is presented, as shown with the code provided below, yet I'm unable to get it to properly work. The issue being that the "random" colors are always the same and are generated in the same order.

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

extension UIView {

    func setGradientBackground() {

        let redValue = CGFloat(drand48())
        let greenValue = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blueValue = CGFloat(drand48())

        let redValue2 = CGFloat(drand48())
        let greenValue2 = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blueValue2 = CGFloat(drand48())

        let random = UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 1).cgColor
        let random2 = UIColor(red: redValue2, green: greenValue2, blue: blueValue2, alpha: 1).cgColor

        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = bounds
        gradient.colors = [random, random2]

        return layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `drand48`, you need to seed it (e.g. with `srand48`). The quick and dirty solution would be to seed it with some value derived from time from the number of seconds passed since some reference date or the like.

Even better, I’d suggest using `CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)` instead, which doesn’t require any seeding.

```
extension UIView {
    func addGradientBackground() {
        let random = UIColor.random().cgColor
        let random2 = UIColor.random().cgColor

        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = bounds
        gradient.colors = [random, random2]

        layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    static func random() -> UIColor {
        let red = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
        let green = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
        let blue = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

---

For what it’s worth, we should appreciate that this technique of adding a sublayer is problematic if the view changes size (e.g., you rotate the device, etc.). You’d have to manually hook into `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `layoutSubviews` and adjust this gradient layer `frame`. I might instead suggest actually having a `UIView` subclass that does this gradient layer.

```
@IBDesignable
class RandomGradientView: UIView {
    override static var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self }
    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { return layer as! CAGradientLayer }

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
    }
}

private extension RandomGradientView {
    func configure() {
        let random = UIColor.random().cgColor
        let random2 = UIColor.random().cgColor
        gradientLayer.colors = [random, random2]
    }
}
```

Because this `UIView` subclass actually specifies the layer class to be used for the main backing layer, and because that main layer always resizes automatically as the view changes size, then it will gracefully handle any size changes (including animated ones).

All of the having been said, I appreciate the convenience of the extension (you can apply it to existing `UIView` subclasses), but you have to offset that with the more cumbersome process of handling frame size changes. It’s your choice, but I wanted to provide the alternative.